# File Extension That's Viewable but not Copiable

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I want to upload some text content as pdf or powerpoint(or slides), but I don't want the text to be copied. I know if I convert the pdf page to a picture, then the text won't be able to be copied since the text will be part of the picture. But I'm not sure if there is a way to have pictures combined like a pdf.(Maybe converting the pages to pictures, then putting the pictures on the pages of a new pdf could work)

So I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to lock the text from being copied by someone else.(The files are currently stored as ppt, but I can convert them to pdf.) Thanks!

Comment: anybody who can read it can copy it - via OCR, or if they're that desperate, they can type it out or dictate it to Siri, Dragon etc.

Comment: Fair enough OCR could be used for pictures. But it would still make it harder for people to copy the content.

Comment: then take screenshots & paste then into a pdf.

Comment: is there a way to do it more efficiently for many files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a recent version of PPT, open your file, choose File | Save As and save it as a PowerPoint Picture Presentation.

This converts the slides into PICTURES of slides.